# How can I determine which part of my Wi-Fi is not working?

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

Sometimes when I boot up my laptop, I can't see any wireless networks. The Wi-Fi card seems perfectly fine in the Windows hardware-manager – but the problem occurs on other operating systems as well – and there are no error messages whatsoever.

Everything seems perfectly fine, except no networks show up.

My first guess was that somehow the Wi-Fi antenna got faulty, but since the only workaround is to reboot a few times, and there are no random disconnects when the Wi-Fi is working, this doesn't seem right.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Do you have a hardware switch for your wifi on your laptop?

Comment: it sounds like it is your laptop wireless driver needs to be updated, go to the manufacturer website and updated that driver, sometimes it a Laptop's BIOS update fix it too. I doubt it is the wifi on your laptop.

Comment: i do have a wifi switch. when the wifi is working, the switch works as well. But if the wifi is not working, the switch does not either. @Miroco This is unlikely, since the wifi worked perfectly for years, and the problem occurs on every operating system i tested